# How do I perform database queries in parallel in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, node-fibers

Collection:

```
docs:
  _id
  name
```

Code:

```
names = Docs.findOne(id).name for id in doc_ids
```

But I would like the findOne queries to be sent off in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibly easier alternative is to use `$in` and do the parallel query on the database itself. Here's an example in CoffeeScript:

```
ids = ['abc123', 'def456', 'hij789']
names = (doc.name for doc in Docs.find({_id: $in: ids}, {fields: name: 1}).fetch())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict your query to a certain subsets of fields, e.g.

```
names = _.pluck(Docs.find({_id:{$in:doc_ids}}, {
  fields: {name:1}
}).fetch(), 'name');
```